# I'm trying to create a stack in c using structures but my push function doesn't work

Tags: c, struct, stack

I'm trying to create a stack in C using structures but the `push()` function I wrote is acting strangely. I'm sure it is something obvious that I'm missing but I just couldn't figure out what.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 50

typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int items[STACK_SIZE];
}
STACK;

void push(STACK* st, int newitem)
{
    st->top++;
    st->items[st->top] = newitem;
    printf("%d", st->items[st->top]);
}


int main()
{
    int n = 1;
    STACK* st;

    printf("test 1\n");
    
    st->top = -1;

    push(st, n);
    
    printf("test 2\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

DevCpp only compiles but doesn't execute the code. OnlineGDB runs it but only prints the first test.

Comment: You initialized a pointer, not a real variable. You should either write `STACK st;` or `STACK *st = malloc(sizeof(STACK));`

Comment: Close to a typo: you only declare a **pointer** to a `STACK` structure and never initialize it. You must have it point to an existing object. For example `STACK st0; STACK *st = &st0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your variable `STACK* st;` was never initialized properly.

##### Some Important Points:

- Don't assign `-1` to the length (`top`), `0` would be better
- `STACK* st;` should be just `STACK st;`
- Your function `void push(STACK* st, int newitem)` should be declared with `static` linkage.
- Write `st->top++`
- Pass `st` variable by address to the `push()` function
- Instead of using bare `return 0;`, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`.
- As your total `STACK_SIZE` is only `50` so, `int` will be sufficient. But as your `STACK_SIZE` grows use `size_t` for your length(`top`).
- use `int main(void) { }`, instead of `int main() { }`
- **NOTE: If `STACK_SIZE` and `top` becomes equal means your `array` is filled completely then further addition of data will lead to [*Undefined Behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).**

##### Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 50

typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int items[STACK_SIZE];
}
STACK;

static void push(STACK* st, int newitem)
{
    if(st->top == STACK_SIZE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "stack size reached maximum length\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    st->items[st->top++] = newitem;
    printf("%d\n", st->items[st->top - 1]); // we added +1 to `top` in the above line
}


int main(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    STACK st;
    printf("test 1\n");
    st.top = 0;
    push(&st, n); //pass by address

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That's basic usage of C. You give a pointer to the function.